# Почему сайт медленно загружается?

Tags: php, администрирование

Что это может быть - сайт небольшой, чуть ли не сайт-визитка, в общем, размером с окно браузера, а тормозит. Написан на пхп, имеет только 3 png картинки. Больше всего подтормаживает при отправке сообщения с помощью `mail()`

Comment: сайт написан на чем? Какая-то CMS используется? хостинг платный? Может ссылку на сайт как-то покажете?

Comment: Написан головой (я думаю, что она есть). Без СМS.
http://content-studio.net.ua

Comment: @binliz, хостинг платный

Comment: @binliz, только там текст письма культурно пиши)) Люди будут читать.))

Comment: Сайт у вас летает. Не вижу проблем, письмо от меня просто для теста, может у вас медленный канал? Счетчик медленно грузится но вы с этим ничего не сделаете так часто бывает.

Comment: Спасибо за проверочку. Наверное потому что у меня интернет 3g. А как вообще сайтик-то? Есть замечания? Что не так? Первый сайт, все-таки

Comment: Угу, всё летает, от Питера вообще 7 хопов.

P.S. Вообще отдавать такое динамикой - смысл?

Comment: ну как вам сказать :), я немного посложнее проекты делаю, и явно не так как вы. ошибки есть в оформлении это похоже на homepage студента. По структуре ничего сказать не могу но увеен что если будете изучать толковую литературу у вас все получится

Comment: в сочи 11 хопов в нетешине 2

Comment: из Таиланда 24 хопа, скорость норм.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**mail()** - функция которая выполняется на сервере, от легкости сайта не зависит. Тут скорее всего либо хостинг тормозит, либо задан некорректный адрес, или отправка вообще запрещена.

а еще можете почитать [тут](http://otvety.google.ru/otvety/thread?tid=718dd5167f92ad8a)